# Python variables combinations?

Tags: python

So I have the following dictionaries which are filled with values (Here I've shortened them to 1 value each)

```
Sl1 = {"A1":1}  
Sl2 = {"A2":5}
```

And so on...
Now in the program I need to change one of the values. In SL1 there are values A1 to I1 and in Sl2, A2 to I2 and so on with lists up to Sl9.
Now if I want to change the value in A6 for example I tried to get the second letter so 6 and do:

```
"Sl"+"6"[A6] = 8
```

I knew this was'nt going to work. Is there anyway I can do anything similar without having to join the lists (That would ruin the rest of my code :( )

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to use dynamic variable names, you should have been using another dictionary or list.

Comment: check the "duplicate" link, but stay away from the `exec` and `eval` answers. Really unsafe.